# QSqlRelationalDelegate From QSortFilterProxyModel, Shows Text Not Id

Tags: python, qt, delegates, pyqt, qtableview

I have a `QSqlRelationalTableModel` feeding a `QDataWidgetMapper`.  It also feeds a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, the proxy then feeding a `QTableView`.  Have tried for three hours, searched here & also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809782/make-qsqlrelationaldelegate-work-with-qsortfilterproxymodel):

The `QTableView` needs custom delegates, it seems `QSqlRelationalDelegate` is the logical option, something like:

```
class TableDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QSqlRelationalDelegate .__init__(self)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, i):
        if i.column() == 1:
            editor = QComboBox(parent)
            editor.setModel(ComboModel)
            editor.setModelColumn(ComboModelVisible)
            return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, i):
        if i.column() == 1:
            print i.model().data(i).toInt()
```

This shows the populated `QComboBox`, but prints the tuple (0, False).  Using`print i.model().data(i).toString()` prints the visual text of the ComboBox, rather than the id integer.  Although `i` references the index location, I don't see why it's returning the related SQL table's text content, rather than the id of the base table that's to be read from/written to.  Also tried changing to `print i.model().data(i, Qt.EditRole).toString()`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the `0` in `(0, False)` the index of that item in the Combobox?

Comment: Hi dilbert.  It says (0, False) irrespective of the row.  With i.model().data(i)toString() however, it correctly prints the text value as listed in the table.

Comment: Ok. Are you trying to load new data into the combobox ? I think that's what's `setEditorData` is used for.